# Wordpress - getting error for wp_enqueue_media()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, upload, media

I am trying to build up a form where user can request some post information including feature image. For uploading the image i have used wp_enqueue_media() which works nicely in all free themes locally but when i install it in main server(premium theme) i got below error through firebug-console. Please check the error screenshot:
[image]

When i click on the error link it shows me the 'plupload.full.min.js' file which locates to `wp-include/js/plupload/` folder.

I don't understand actually why i am getting this error. I used below function to include `wp_enqueue_media()` through plugin folder:

```
 function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();

 }

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts');
```

I need your kind help to get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have HTML in your javascript, so you did something wrong ?

Comment: I don't believe so because this is onload error. Not after clicking the UPLOAD button.

Comment: Uhm, I wasn't asking, I'm telling you that the console screenshot shows that you have HTML in the javascript, and that the parser doesn't expect it, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just noticed, live site has another plugin installed named 'Autoptimize' which compressed all of wp core js files :( When i deactivate it my wp_media_upload() working :)